# php mysql query for blog data increases/load memory on web server

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have the following code that generates an image from database which can be cached for a month.

I had a bot attack that was loading the image about 3000 times in a minute. It crushed my web servers while the database server was fine. (I have since started using cloud front to cache at edge servers which solves that issue)

Why does this code cause web servers to crash under load as it is just a simple indexed query for a LONGBLOB. Does it use a lot of memory?

```
    $file_id = 1;
    //Gets file from database based on id SELECT * FROM files WHERE file_id = 1
    $file = $this->Appfile->get($file_id);

    $this->load->helper('file');
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000");
    header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', strtotime('+1 month')).' GMT');
    header('Pragma: cache');
    header("Content-type: ".get_mime_by_extension($file->file_name));
    echo $file->file_data;
```

Comment: Well, PHP/MySQL certainly won't serve files as effectively as a web server and filesystem.  3000 times in a minute is a great deal of requests.

Comment: The database server CPU went up a bit but was otherwise fine. The web servers load, memory was crushed and couldn't respond.

Comment: @ChrisMuench are you using Apache? have you tweaked the memory?

Comment: Nothing here looks like it should use a lot of memory, assuming the images are small.  But if you're instantiating a framework or something for every request, I could see it causing some excess memory.

Comment: @ChrisMuench you could always benchmark with memory_get_peak_usage

Comment: 3000 per minute means there are 50 per second on average. Even if the requests take 1/2 second each, it's likely that at any given moment, there are 25 concurrent PHP requests each storing a copy of `$file->file_data` in its own RAM space. Yes, this can add up, eventually causing the host to start swapping RAM out to virtual memory, which causes a spike in load and slow performance.